# Using a javascript color wheel to use variables between scripts

Tags: javascript

```
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
    Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">



    <h2>Example 2</h2>

    <button class="jscolor {valueElement:'chosen-value', onFineChange:'setTextColor(this)'}">
            Pick text color
    </button>

    HEX value: <input id="chosen-value" value="000000">

    <script>
    function setTextColor(picker) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('myDiv')[0].style.color = '#' + picker.toString()
    }
    </script>
```

I went to change mydiv to specifically a variable called colorScaleValue in my lower script but it doesn't transfer over. 
Any help?

Comment: There isn't an element with the tag name `myDiv`. The tag name is the text used in the elements tag, for example all `<button>` elements have the tag name `"button"`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek hey can JS use variables that's declared in another script in the same file? If not what are common work arounsd

Comment: Yes you can use variables declared in other files, everything is just parsed top-down in the end.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ok can I use id's to signal them, It hasn't been working out great for me  , I need to set a variable to be called from another function inside another function